# Missing Request header "Accept" with Spring 5.x

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I was using Spring version 4.x, and with the upgrade to 5.x  - I have noticed that some of the API requests are failing (MissingRequestHeaderException) if the Accept header is not provided in the request.

The interface doesn't really need them, as it is not being used. The API's without it in the interface works fine. A solution would be to remove it from all the API's wherever it's there. But that's not a path we want to take now, I am looking for a general solution that could be applied to all API's without having to change each one separately.

Is there a way I could ask Spring to ignore this parameter in the interface ?

Or maybe handle the MissingRequestHeaderException so as to ignore it and process the API request, is that possible?

The API Interface:

```
public Void setEmployeeDetails( @PathVariable( "employeeId" )Integer employeeId, @Valid @RequestBody EDetails eDetails, String accept )
```

The API Controller implementing the interface:

```
Void setEmployeeDetails( @ApiParam(value = "ID of the employee.",required=true ) @PathVariable("employeeId") Integer employeeId,
                   @ApiParam(value = "" ,required=true ) @Valid @RequestBody EDetails eDetails, 
                   @RequestHeader("Accept") String accept)
```

Comment: Include your controller definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javadoc of `MissingRequestHeaderException` says:

> `ServletRequestBindingException` subclass that indicates that a **request header expected in the method parameters of an `@RequestMapping` method** is not present.

Checking the Spring source code, it also seems like that exception is only thrown by `RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver`, which says:

> Resolves **method arguments annotated with `@RequestHeader`** except for `Map` arguments. See `RequestHeaderMapMethodArgumentResolver` for details on `Map` arguments annotated with `@RequestHeader`.
>
> An `@RequestHeader` is a named value resolved from a request header. **It has a required flag** and a default value to fall back on when the request header does not exist.

So it would seem that if you're getting that error, it's because your code is asking for the `Accept` header and did not specify `required=false`, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public void foo(@RequestHeader(name="Accept", required=false) String accept) {
    //                                        ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
    //                                           Missing!
    ...
}
```

Comment: Fine. As evident by the last (code) line of the question.

Comment: I was looking at a solution that doesn't involve changing all the API's individually. Moreover my swagger code-gen always generates it with this parameter and I do not think there's a way to tell it not to ATM.

Comment: @Chillax Seems you have *bad code*, so you should *fix it*. Why would API have been coded to require `Accept` header, if it wasn't needed? Either it *is* needed and you need to fix the code that doesn't send it, or it *isn't* needed and you need to fix API to not require it.